# Determining whether $\hat{\beta}_1$ is unbiased

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood, mean-square-error

The average annual temperature for 12 selected years in Berlin can be read from the following table:

| Year | 1890 | 1900 | 1911 | 1922 | 1930 | 1943 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| temperature | 8.1 | 8.8 | 9.7 | 7.4 | 9.2 | 9.3 |

The second part of the table

| Year | 1966 | 1967 | 1983 | 1998 | 2000 | 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| temperature | 8.8 | 9.6 | 9.7 | 9.5 | 10.5 | 11.1 |

We will explain the temperature $Y_i$ in year $x_i$ using a simple linear regression model
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i, \; \; \; \; \; i = 1, ..., 12
$$
Where $\varepsilon_1, ... , \varepsilon_{12} \sim N(0, 0.5)$ are independent random variables and $\beta_0$, $\beta_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ are
unknown parameters.

Is $\hat{\beta}_1$ unbiased? Find the $MSE(\hat{\beta}_1)$.

I have already found that $\hat{\beta}_0 = -23.9$ and $\hat{\beta}_1 = 0.017$. I have managed to solve it using R code, but i want to be able to do it by hand.

So far i know that $MSE(\hat{\Theta}) = E[(\hat{\Theta} - \theta)^2]$ and but i'm not sure i know what my $\hat{\Theta}$ and $\theta$ is here.

I havet tried to find information in my book about how i determine if $\hat{\beta}_1$ is unbiased, but haven't been able to find anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

Note that i am referring to the book: Introduction to Probability Statistics and Random Processes by Hossein Pishro-Nik.

We have the following information from section 8.5.2:
\begin{align*}
    \hat{\beta}_1 &= \frac{s_{xy}}{s_{xx}} \\
    \bar{x} &= \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n}{n}   \\
    \bar{y} &= \frac{y_1 + y_2 + ... + y_n}{n}   \\
    s_{xx} &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \\
    s_{xy} &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})
\end{align*}
I can then use that to show that $\hat \beta_o$ is unbiased, by simplifying $E[\hat \beta_o]$ using information from section 8.5.2.
\begin{align*}
    E[\hat \beta_1] &= \frac{s_{xy}}{s_{xx}} \\
    &= \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \\
    &= \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})\hat{y}_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
\end{align*}
%
Above we have that $\hat{y}_i = (y_i - \bar{y})$ and since we also have $\hat{y}_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i$ (from the linear regression model), then we can substitute it in the equation:
\begin{align*}
    &= \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i)}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \\
    &= \frac{ \beta_0 \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}) + \beta_1 \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}) x_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2} 
\end{align*}
%
Above I remove the parentheses, after which I multiply $x_i$ into $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})$ below:
\begin{align*}
    &= \frac{ \beta_0 \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}) + \beta_1 \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i^2 - \bar{x}x_i)}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \\
    &= \beta_1 \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i^2 - \bar{x}x_i)
\end{align*}
Above we realized that the term $\beta_0 \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}) = 0$ because the term $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})$ is just the sum of a data set's deviations from their mean value and it is known that the sum of this gives zero. The same applies to the term $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ \
%
Now I use the summation rule to get the following:
\begin{align*}
    &= \beta_1 \bigg(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i^2) - \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (\bar{x}x_i)\bigg) \\
    &= \beta_1 \bigg(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i^2) - n\bar{x}^2\bigg)
\end{align*}
Above we remembered that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = n\bar{x}$, so we replaced the value $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\bar{x}$ with $n\bar{x}\bar{x} = n\bar{x}^2$. Now I realize that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = (n\bar{x}^2)$ and thus get the following result:
\begin{align*}
    &= \beta_1 \bigg(n\bar{x}^2 - n\bar{x}^2\bigg) \\
    &= \beta_1   
\end{align*}
Therefore i get:
$$ E[\hat \beta_1] = \beta_1 $$
This means that $\hat{\beta}_1$ is unbiased.

Comment: While expanding everything ought to work algebraically, it is a horrible idea, specially with multivariate statistics (which ultimately is the only statistics that is worth learning).\

Comment: Can you elaborate, because i'm not sure i understand what you mean? Was my solution correct and incorrect?

Comment: Your steps are confusing because you seem to be using the expectation operator, but you do not actually make it clear when or where you are taking expectations.

Comment: Is there a specific place where that's the case or is it just generally everywhere?

Comment: @Mohammed your calculations seem correct, you are assuming that in the model "$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \varepsilon$" only $\varepsilon$ is random in the right hand side. This assumption is quite common; another common assumption is that $x$ is also random but we are conditioning on the observed values (so that it is no longer random). Your $s_{xx}$ and $s_{xy}$ are wrong as they both require a $\frac{1}{n}$ factor in front of them. $\hat y = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 x.$ Again, this method is extremely inefficient and cumbersome. Learn statistics using vectors (e.g. Seber's book).

Comment: In the course that i'm taking we use the mentioned book and the problems and exam is based on only that book. So even though the method is extremely inefficient and cumbersome, it's the method that i need to learn and understand. May i also ask you if  can you elaborate on why $s_{xx}$ and $s_{xy}$ is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The MLE is indeed unbiased. In fact, more is true. We have $$ \hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$ Thus $$E(\hat \beta \mid X) = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T E(y\mid X) = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\beta = \beta$$
Taking expectations on both sides shows $E(\hat \beta) = \beta$. Note the only assumptions we have used are $X^TX$ is invertible and $E(y\mid X) = X\beta$.

Comment: Where would we get that from? How do we know that we have this $\hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$

Comment: There are two ways to derive this, one uses linear algebra and the other uses calculus. If one wants to find $\hat \beta$ such that $\|y-X\hat \beta\|$ is minimized, standard results from linear algebra imply that the error $y-X\hat\beta$ is orthogonal to the approximation $X\hat \beta$. Thus $y-X\hat \beta$ lies in the left null space of $X$, and we are led to $$X^T(y-X\hat \beta) = 0$$. That is, $$\hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$ As for the calculus way, first show the loss function $$L(\beta) = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)$$ is convex.

Comment: Thus $\hat \beta$ minimizes the loss provided $\nabla L(\hat \beta) = 0$. Computations show that $$\nabla L((X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty) = 0$$

Comment: It is instructive to think about the statistical interpretation of the linear algebra derivation.

Comment: I'm sorry but is this the only way possible to determine if it's unbiased? Even though i'm sure what you are saying makes sense i just can't understand it and it doesn't seem familiar, but thank you for trying to help anyway.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with linear algebra or multiple linear regression, then Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference has a section on univariate linear regression, where analogous results are derived, without linear algebra. Really the key is just to find a closed form for $\hat \beta_1$ and then use properties of expectation operator and your model.

Comment: The material that i am familiar with is the book Introduction to Probability Statistics and Random Processes by Hossein Pishro-Nik. Unfortunately I am not familiar with anything that isn't included in the book.

Comment: From the book that i mentioned i do have the following: Let $\hat{\Theta} = h(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ be a point estimator for a parameter $\theta$. We say that $\hat{\Theta}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ if: $$B(\hat{\Theta}) = 0 $$ for all possible values of $\theta$. I assume that is what you showed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146244/discussion-between-andrew-zhang-and-mohammed).